# Web development implementing the form onclick event

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I made this log-in and register form in which an onclick submit button of the form its display which form is submitted, left or right to implement it. I have used onclick property and passed a function to it `fun()` which has one parameter of the type no. So I used two functions `fun(0)` and fun`(1)` used to display a message which forms submitted by the user but it does not display the message.
And also I have a problem with the CSS it's not scaling according to the screen size as I used bootstrap for CSS and try the width, position property scale in % but then also it's not working.

```js
function fun(Number n) {
  if (n === 1) {
    document.getElementsByClassName('m1').style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    document.getElementsByClassName('m2').style.display = 'none';
  }
  document.getElementsByClassName('modal').style.display = 'flex';
}
```

```css
body {
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, #fff722, #ff26f9);
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-family: open sans, helvetica neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}

input[type=radio] {
    width: 9%;
}

input, #e {
    width: 100%;
}

input[type=submit] {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.row {
    position: relative;
}

form {
    font-size: 20px;
    border-bottom: solid 5px #dedfe0;
    border-right: solid 5px #dedfe0;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 80px;
}

label {
    font-family: arial;
    color: #0000ff;
}

#log {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    transform: translate(50, 50);
}

button:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.modal, .modal1 {
    display: none;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.modal-content {
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, #fff722, #ff26f9);
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2%;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border: solid 5px rgba(100, 0, 50, 0.5);
    left: 500px;
    top: 180px;
}

.close {
    position: absolute;
    right: 25px;
    top: 0;
    color: black;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover, .close:focus {
    color: red;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.animate {
    animation: zoom 10000;
}

@keyframes zoom {
    from {
        transform: scale(0)
    }
    to {
        transform: scale(2)
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="row">
        <form class="jumbotron" class="column" id="register">
            <h1 class="container " style="border: solid 3px grey; color:magenta;
      "><b>REGISTER<b></b></h1><br>
            <label>First Name:</label><input type="text"><br>
            <label>Last Name:</label> <input type="text"><br>
            <label>D.O.B:</label> <input type="date"><br>
            <label>City:</label> <input type="text"><br>
            <label>Mobile No.: </label>
            <select style=" width: 20%;">
        <option>+91</option>
        <option>+92</option>
        <option>+93</option>
        <option>+94</option>
        <option>+95</option>
      </select> <input type="text"><br>
            <label>Gender:</label>
            <div style=" "> <input type="radio" value="Male" name="Gender">Male
                <input type="radio" value="Female" name="Gender">Female
                <input type="radio" value="Other" name="Gender">Other<br></div>
            <label>Employment Status:</label>
            <select id="e">
        <option>Employed</option>
        <option>Unemployed</option>
      </select><br><br><br>
            <input type="submit" onclick="fun(0)" class="btn-info btn-lg" value=Register>
            <input type="reset" class="btn-info btn-lg" value=Reset>
        </form>


        <div class="column" id="log">
            <form class="jumbotron">
                <h1 style="border: solid 3px grey; color:magenta;"><b>LOG-IN</b></h1><br>
                <label>Email-Id:</label><input type="email"><br>
                <label>Username:</label><input type="text"><br>
                <label>Password:</label><input type="Password" min,="5"></br><br><br>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-lg " onclick="fun(1)" value="LOG-IN">

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <nav class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <span onclick="document.querySelector('.modal').style.display='none'" class="close">&times;</span>
            <div style="border:solid 5px #dedfe0" class="container">
                <h3 class='m1'>Left form submited</h3>
                <h3 class='m2'>Right form submited</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>




</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: this post has severe grammar and formatting issues. please consider shortening it and cleaning it up. also `fun(1)` and `fun(2)` are not 2 seperate functions but one function with separate parameters.

Comment: first of all, remove the exta bracket in the `if` statement in your javascript code, in this line: `document.getElementsByClassName('m1').style.display='none';}`, that } is closing the if before you want it to be closed

Comment: `function fun(Number n)`  is not how you declare a parameter in javascript.

Comment: @  Jon P then how should I declare the function.

Comment: @  Ramon de Vries I want to hide m1 class for fun(1)  function. So how to do it